# Symmetries of the Interaction Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, hamiltonian

This question is about symmetry properties of the interaction term in a given quantum theory.    What is there to be said about whether or not the interaction Hamiltonian term may be written in a symmetric or anti-symmetric form in a given theory?  Which physical properties would this reflect.  We may assume this operator is Hermitian, so its conjugate-transpose equals itself.   Of particular interest to me at the moment, however, is properties of it's *non*-transposed conjugate.  For instance,  if this operator call it $\Omega_H$ were anti-symmetric then its non-transpose conjugate should obey the property $\Omega_H^*=-\Omega_H$, while if it were symmetric it could be deduced that its non-transposed conjugate should obey $\Omega^*=\Omega$.  Which physical properties, if any, should contribute to this aspect?

Comment: See chapter 2 of the Weinberg's QFT [book](https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Theory-Fields-Foundations/dp/0521670535)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't symmetry/antisymmetry of the Hamiltonian operator dependent on the basis in the Hilbert space? Note that an operator is like a rank (1,1) tensor with one up and one down index, so $H_a^{\;b} = \pm H_b^{\;a}$ is **not** a tensor equation and thus is dependent on the basis, and mustn't have any physical interpretation!

Comment: I should emphasize that we are discussing an interaction term specifically, and the question regards properties the make the desired symmetries. The chosen basis shouldn't effect a physical outcome,true;that's not exactly what I'm getting at though.

Comment: @Nogueira, correct me if I missed something, but I didn't find that the section adresses cases of this specific aspect of the generating function.

Comment: @Solenoden Paradoxus I understand your point, but I'm not entirely on board with the idea that a preferred basis is entirely arbitrary to any given physical theory, which a particular H plays a part in describing, even if the reasons for preference were purely of calculative or passive nature, but this is an interesting point to debate.